# Prevent python package from updating

Tags: python, package, updates, plotly-dash, stability

I'm working on a product for a client and I'm thinking about using plotly's dash package.

However, the client raised the concern that using packages could require frequent maintenance as the package develops by day and is updated regularly.

Is there a way to use the current version of a package and keep it the same way, in terms of its version? In other words, without having to update it? I mean sure, I can just refrain from updating the package, however, if methods become deprecated and replaced by others, they will stop working, right?

Comment: Python packages don't update themselves unless you explicitly perform an update, e.g. via `pip install --upgrade`. So long as you're using a virtual environment for your project, you shouldn't have to worry about dependencies changing underneath your feet.

Comment: It seems you don't understand that deprecation only means that new methods are *recommended* over old ones. The old ones, if the codebase is good, will still work. Just don't update packages unless you find a bug.

Comment: thanks for the help!